# populating radio group box from database at creation in delphi

Tags: delphi, constructor, properties, components

In Delphi 7 I have created a radio group component whose items are obtained from a database table. The table used is represented as one of the components properties. The procedure populate() successfully populates the group when called at runtime. However I want to populate the group at creation, when I try to reference the tablename property (through getTableName()) even at the end the constructor method, it is empty. How can I do this? At what point does the private variable fTablename get populated?

Comment: Presumably you are asking to know when the properties are streamed. You could override Loaded. What if the properties are set at runtime though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to reference the tablename property (through getTableName()) even at the end the constructor method, it is empty.

That is because design-time property values have not been streamed from the DFM into the component yet during construction.  That happens after construction is finished.

> How can I do this? At what point does the private variable fTablename get populated?

When its property is assigned, such as during DFM streaming.

If you want to act on design-time values at run-time, you need to override the virtual `Loaded()` method, which gets called after the DFM is streamed into the component.

Also, any property setters that perform real-time updates using existing property values should first check the `ComponentState` property for the `csLoading` and `csReading` flags before performing those updates. If the flags are set, delay the updates until `Loaded()` is called.

Comment: I have subsequently found they are not even populated when trying to access via the afterconstruction method. Not sure why I got a -1

Comment: @TonyWolff right, because the DFM is streamed into the component **after** construction is completed first.